# How to move a list of files (the list contains path + filename) in python?

Tags: python, list, move, shutil

I have a list like this:

```
 ../../topics/A100/A100/A.dita
 ../../topics/A100/A200/B.dita
 ../../topics/A100/A300/C.dita
```

I have a folder named *_inactive* in the A100, A200, A300 folders. I want to move the files referenced in the list to the  *_inactive* fodler in the file's folder.

I tried `shutil.move` without success.

```
for z in maradek:
    shutil.move(z, '_inactive')
```

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: What error with `shutil.move` do you get?

Comment: The problem is that I have relative links in the list. I get the following error. No such file or directory. Should I alter the list with regexp?

Comment: `for z in maradek:
    shutil.move(z, '_inactive')` maradek is the name of the list

Comment: Where is the _inactive folder? Maybe you should provide the full path instead of relative path

Comment: There is an _inactive folder in the A100, A200, A300 folders. The relative path is give, it isred from a txt file.

Comment: It would be better, however I am not able to convert tha path to absolute

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `os` module. Then perhaps `os.system('mv path/to/file destination/of/file')`.